# Implicit pointer conversions to POD pointer

Tags: c++

I have a lot of functions with such signatures:

```
//libraries I can't change
void f1(double *x);
void f2(double *x1, double *x2);
...
```

And a lot of code that uses them:

```
//my code
double x; ... f1(&x);
double x1[] = ...; double x2 = ...; f2(x1, &x2);
...
```

For some reasons I decided to use in My code special class instead of ordinary doubles:

```
struct DoubleClass {
    double x_;
    ...
    //constructors, overloaded arithmetic operators and casts to double
};
```

This DoubleClass behaves like double with some additional functionality that I want. In memory DoubleClass is the same as double. It has only 1 member and sizeof(DoubleClass) == sizeof(double).
And so I want to redeclare all doubles in my code with something like

```
#define double DoubleClass
```

But I can't compile code because there is no conversion from DoubleClass* to double*. I can't change functions f1, f2. So I wanted to ask if I can somehow define an  implicit conversion from DoubleClass* to double* or maybe there are some tricks that will allow to do it.

Comment: That's probably a very bad idea, could you backup with some reasoning why you actually want to do this?

Comment: `#define` of any language keyword, including `double` results in undefined behaviour.   There is also no way of defining new implicit conversions between two dissimilar pointer types (e.g. from `DoubleClass *` to `double *`).  You would be better off doing a global replace, with your editor, of `double` with `DoubleClass`  (except in class `DoubleClass`, of course).   If you later decide to revert from using your `struct DoubleClass` to `double`, all you need to do is remove the struct declaration and `#define DoubleClass double`.

Comment: I want to do this because I need to add some functionality to comparison operators (I want to know if there are cases when 2 very closed doubles are compared and determined as not the same because they differs a little). Maybe Peter is right and global replace with editor is the best choice.

Comment: Providing comparison operators for your `DoubleClass` is fine - albeit, having two distinct values compare as equal would cause a surprise to users of your type.   But that has has nothing to do with needing to implement implicit conversion between `double *` and `DoubleClass *`, which is not possible.

Comment: To be honest there will be no users of this type. It is a temporary class. I've written it only to check some ideas about unexpected results that I've recieved. This code models some fixed point computations with double arithmetics. So when you have an integer = 0 and if you add 1 a thousand times you will get 1000. And you know it. However when you try to model it with double numbers you sometimes get something you haven't expected.

Comment: So DoubleClass behaves exactly as double except it warns you if there were cases when during computations there were comparisons of 2 very very close doubles.

Comment: Wrap your library and use the wrapped functions / classes.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `f1()`, and the second parameter of `f2()`, you can override `operator&` to return a `double*`:

```
struct DoubleClass {
    double x_;
    ...
    double* operator&() { return &x_; }
};
```

```
DoubleClass x = ...;
f1(&x);
```

```
DoubleClass x2 = ...;
f2(..., &x2);
```

But no operator overloading in `DoubleClass` can help you with the first parameter of `f2()` because a `DoubleClass[]` array is simply not the same as a `double[]` array. An explicit type-cast would be needed:

```
DoubleClass x1[] = ...;
f2(reinterpret_cast<double*>(&x1[0]), ...);
```

Or else use a wrapper with a conversion operator:

```
template <const int N>
struct DoubleClassArray
{
    DoubleClass arr_[N];
    ...
    operator double*() { return arr_; }
};
```

```
DoubleClassArray<...> x = ...;
f2(x1, ...);
```

> And so I want to redeclare all doubles in my code with something like
>
> ```
> #define double DoubleClass
> ```

I would not suggest doing that. But if you do, you have to make sure you protect the `double` inside of `DoubleClass` otherwise it will be changed as well.  Defining overloads would be safer:

```
struct DoubleClass {
    double x_;
    ...
    //DO NOT override operator&!
};

void f1(DoubleClass *x) { f1(reinterpret_cast<double*>(x); }
void f2(DoubleClass *x1, DoubleClass *x2) { f2(reinterpret_cast<double*>(x1), reinterpret_cast<double*>(x2); }
...
```

```
DoubleClass x; ...
f1(&x);
```

```
DoubleClass x1[] = ...;
DoubleClass x2 = ...;
f2(x1, &x2);
```

Answer (score 0):

could you check with subtraction of normal double values instead of overloading operators? if two doubles subtracted is 0 they are precisely equal*

[machine precision floating point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) example, machine precision is a finicky thing*

Comment: Certainly I can. But there are hundreds of places in the code I deal with where I should have to check this. And this code is continiously developed by other people. So I would like to have an easy way to add and to remove such checkings to the program in some cases.